# Does Merging multiple jacoco.exec file reduces merged file size and gives diffrent code Coverage percentage?

Tags: jacoco

I am having having three jacoco.exec files. I am able to merge the files and get an output as a merged.exec file.

But my merged.exec file is smaller than combined file size.
Eg. my file sizes :

```
1st jacoco.exec = 1789 KB = Code Coverage = 4% 
2nd jacoco.exec = 925 KB = Code Coverage = 3% 
3rd jacoco.exec = 510 KB = Code Coverage = 4% 
------------------------- 
Merged.exec = 625 KB = Code Coverage = 5%
========================================================================
```

Due to this I am getting different code Coverage percentage from my final output.

I am not understanding the calculation of the merged file and how come it is more.
Please, explain the calculation behind the merge process.

Answer (score 1):

If a jacoco.exec file is created with "append", it contains data from different sessions. If this file is merged, the data from different sessions are also merged. Therefore the resulting file has a smaller file size.

But the code coverage percentage of the merged file will always be equal or greater.

Related discussions : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/msl5rGuz1dw
From marc (from jacoco)

> indeed this can be correct. The exec files contain a execution data
>   dump  per session. When merging the execution data for every class is 
>   consolidated and written as single dump.
>
> So if your exec filed contain multiple sessions, the merged version of
>   thif file will be smaller. You can verify by looking into the exec
>   files: